# Is there an plugin or function in wordpress to calculate price in variable options of quantity

Tags: wordpress, forms, variables, price

I'm setting a wordpress web and want to calculate variable price when i choose an option of quantity in product page.

This is for a new wordpress web. In the past week, I've tried editing variable price on wordpress but in the end doesn't work.

I expect a label shows a diferent price when I choose a quantity (option button)

[Price change when I change a diferente quantity on wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5c1r.png)